# ¿Como definir una clave primaria no incremental en Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

Una consulta. Tengo la tabla clientes con los campos id y nombre.

Por medio de un lector de código de barras leo una tarjeta, y quiero guardar el numero que tiene dicha tarjeta (ej: 123465) en el campo id, y que dicho campo sea mi clave primaria.

Laravel, me guarda por defecto el id como incremental, sin embargo si yo le saco la opción de incremental y le pongo `integer`, al hacer el `migrate`, no me guarda el id como clave primaria.

Lo que necesito es crear el campo id, pero que el mismo sea clave primaria y a su vez no sea incremental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solucion es declarar el campo como normalmente lo haces, pero agregar el indice por medio de:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary('id');
});
```

tal como lo muestra la documentacion [Adding indexes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes)